# Is there a tool that will help me construct a list of games with a more specific game mechanic?

Tags: mechanics

I would like to construct a list of games that have a particular mechanic, but with a twist. Dice rolling is the mechanic I am interested in but specifically with Non-numeric, partially numeric, or otherwise numbered dice (essentially, anything different from the ordinary 1 to n numbering with n being the number of sides of dice).

Obviously asking for such a list is outside of the rules, but if possible I would like to find tools to help me find them for myself. Unfortunately BGG, while it has search by game mechanic, does not allow easy drilling by specifics, and with one as broad as Dice rolling, searching through a list of pictures of 18k+ games looking for odd-looking dice would be a fool's errand.

Does anyone know of any site that categorizes games by this admittedly obscure mechanic, or anything else that might help me in this?

Comment: Non-numeric dice is an obscure mechanic?  I think I own more of those than I do games with traditional dice.

Answer (score 1):

How important is this to you? Is this something you are simply curious in? Or is this something you want to put real effort and time into accomplishing for a task or job of some kind?

If it is just a hobby, you could go to your local game stores with a notebook and ask the people there, look at the games there. Repeat at a few other game stores and you should have a nice list. (similar to just browsing games on BGG)

If it is something you want to do more seriously. You could try to contact some of the big board game manufacturers (like Fantasy Flight for instance) And directly ask them which games use non standard N-sided dice.